# Android doesn't release resources from services?

Tags: android

As [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) says:

> Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even
>   if the component that started it is destroyed.

So, if there's an infinite loop in a service, and the system is low on resources, will the service be killed? If yes, so I can't have sure that my service will run till the end?

Comment: **So, if there's an infinite loop in a service, and the system is low on resources, will the service be killed?** - Very possibly but there's a possibility you'll have drained the battery before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes your service can be killed by the OS if it needs the resources if you want to have something always run you need to use `startForeground` but even that does not guarantee it wont be killed just a lot less likely.

using `startForeground` requires you to have a notification in the notification bar to tell the user that there is something running still

Answer (score 0):

You can set a priority of your service asking that it not be terminated but that's something that you should only do if you really, REALLY need it.  Your Service should not be very resource heavy being that there is no UI associated with it though so it would likely not be a good candidate for killing to free up resources.  If your Service is killed it will start again when you try to bind to it so you really shouldn't see a difference as far as your app is concerned.